# Detect errant data over consecutive rows of a Python Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, finance

While operating on a Pandas DataFrame of quarterly earnings dates, and realizing I would want to do quarter-to-quarter (i.e. Q2 to Q3) comparisons, I realized I ought to be certain my data is ordered correctly and also complete.

So, 
1. always the 'correct' quarter (q1->q2->q3->q4->q1->q2...)
2. and isn't missing any quarters (q1->q2->q4->q1->q2->q3) would not be good as missing a q3.

I already have a dataframe I load in, and figured it would make sense to check it in pandas rather than go back and check it preloading.

I came up with what I think are two slightly band-aid solutions to a problem but thought it might be interesting to post the problem and my solutions to see if anyone had some light to shed or found this interesting.  It seems difficult to find Pandas information at times to take me from elementary to intermediate level proficiency.

I guess there is either a more elegant solution for this problem, and probably also a more widely applicable concept I could learn and apply here and also to other problems.  With no further ado.  Or is it ado?...

I have a set of financial earnings data.  It looks something like this:

```
Index   Symbol  Time    Earning_Date    Year    Quarter Last_Quarter
0   AAPL    16:30:00    10/27/2015  2015    Q4  Q3
1   AAPL    16:30:00    7/21/2015   2015    Q3  Q2
2   AAPL    16:30:00    4/27/2015   2015    Q2  Q1
3   AAPL    16:30:00    1/27/2015   2015    Q1  Q4
4   AAPL    16:30:00    10/20/2014  2014    Q4  Q3
5   AAPL    16:30:00    7/22/2014   2014    Q3  Q2
6   AAPL    16:30:00    4/23/2014   2014    Q2  Q1
7   AAPL    16:30:00    1/27/2014   2014    Q1  Q4
8   AAPL    16:30:00    10/28/2013  2013    Q4  Q3
9   AAPL    16:30:00    7/23/2013   2013    Q3  Q2
10  AAPL    16:30:00    4/23/2013   2013    Q2  Q1
11  AAPL    16:30:00    1/23/2013   2013    Q1  Q4
12  AAPL    16:30:00    10/25/2012  2012    Q4  Q3
13  AAPL    16:30:00    7/24/2012   2012    Q3  Q2
14  AAPL    16:30:00    4/24/2012   2012    Q2  Q1
15  AAPL    16:30:00    1/24/2012   2012    Q1  Q4
16  AAPL    16:30:00    10/18/2011  2011    Q4  Q3
17  AAPL    16:30:00    7/19/2011   2011    Q3  Q2
18  AAPL    16:30:00    4/20/2011   2011    Q2  Q1
19  AAPL    16:30:00    1/18/2011   2011    Q1  NaN
```

First of all, full disclosure - I've already populated this DF with a 'solution' to the problem of appending Last_Quarter to each row - i simply used .shift(-1) to populate that.  I'm sure that could've been done better- that data is only as essential to the DF as it helped me solve the problem in my two ways.  But it's fine if we solve the problem without the Last_Quarter column.  Hope that makes sense.

The bigger question is sort of cleaning for potentially missing or erroneous data.  If a stock skipped an earnings quarter, or my data was otherwise corrupt, the sequence might read Index 2 Quarter Q2, Index 3 Quarter Q4, thus Q3 is skipped, and lots of assumptions might then be wrong.  So I wanted to just make sure for all data Q1 follows Q4, Q2 follows Q1, Q3 follows Q2, Q4 follows Q3.

And just kick out an exception at the very least if the data is bad.  Here are two solutions we came up with:

```
    accptbl_qtr_pr_tpls = [('Q3','Q4'),('Q4','Q1'),('Q1','Q2'),('Q2','Q3')]
    rows_that_pass = 0
    rows_total = len(self.df)
    print 'total rows', rows_total
    for accptbl_qtr_pr_tpl in accptbl_qtr_pr_tpls:
        foo = self.df.ix[(self.df['Last_Quarter'] == accptbl_qtr_pr_tpl[0]) & (self.df['Quarter'] == accptbl_qtr_pr_tpl[1])]
        rows_that_pass += len(foo)
    if rows_total != 1+rows_that_pass: # the + 1 is to account for NaN in earliest result last_quarter column
        print 'quarter issue!, exiting'
```

and we also came up with:

```
        if not (((self.df['Last_Quarter'] == 'Q1') & (self.df['Quarter'] == 'Q2')).any() and ((self.df['Last_Quarter'] == 'Q2') & (self.df['Quarter'] == 'Q3')).any() \
           and ((self.df['Last_Quarter'] == 'Q3') & (self.df['Quarter'] == 'Q4')).any() and ((self.df['Last_Quarter'] == 'Q4') & (self.df['Quarter'] == 'Q1')).any()):
            print "bad data"
        else:
            print 'good data'
```

Figured i would throw this up here and find out how clever we are or how ... much time we wasted solving a solved problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write a function to return True or False based on a valid combination of values in Quarter and Last_Quarter, then create a new column with the valid status result by applying the function row-wise.

This will give you the ability to take a slice of the DataFrame with only the good or bad rows.

The function would look something like this:

```
def check_quarters(row):
   # if either Quarter or Last_Quarter is NaN, return False
   if (row['Quarter'] != row['Quarter']) or (row['Last_Quarter'] != row['Last_Quarter']):
      return False
   # check for valid combination when Quarter is Q2 Q3 or Q4
   if int(row['Quarter'][1:2]) - 1 == int(row['Last_Quarter'][1:2]):
      return True
   # check for valid combination when Quarter is Q1
   elif int(row['Quarter'][1:2]) == 1 and int(row['Last_Quarter'][1:2]) == 4:
      return True
   else:
      return False
```

Apply the function to create the new column:

```
df['Valid_Quarters'] = df.apply(check_quarters, axis = 1)
```

Now you can slice the DataFrame to get only the valid rows:

```
df.loc[df['Valid_Quarters'],:]
```

Comment: thanks Joe for your attention and it seems like a well thought out answer.  I will test this tomorrow.  The idea of using .apply / a function , which would then flag good data, and then slicing the DF on it didn't occur to me.  I appreciate also you taking care of the q4 special case - hehe.  I sometimes forget to do that myself.  Finally, I guess, is it 'obvious' that by calling apply and the check_quarters argument in there, along with axis = 1, that you are sort of 'operating' on rows?  I guess that's what axis = 1 does - tells the func you want to operate row-wise?  thank you very much -

Comment: it seems like this works.  I at least have implemented it and tested using a simple 'drop' method as suggested in the other answer.  How might you sort of kick the script out or otherwise handle the 'exception' if indeed any member of Valid_Quarters comes back as False (besides the last one in the index, which will 'always' come back false to the last quarter being NaN there).  Again I could think of a few ideas but yours may be smarter.  Mine will go back to using a length or .any check sort of how I did that earlier on.  And then kicking the script out.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can convert earnings to time series and then resample. My `df` below is your example DataFrame.

```
#Drop a couple of row to test
df = df.drop([3,8,10]) 

#I'm creating a timestamp index, according to Year & Quarter columns. But if they are guaranteed to be conssitent with Earning_Date, you can use that date directly.
df.index = pd.PeriodIndex(df['Year'].astype(str)  + df['Quarter'], freq='Q').to_timestamp() #

#Some random data pretending to be earnings
df['Earnings'] = np.random.rand(len(df))

earnings = df['Earnings'].sort_index().resample('QS') #this will fill in NaN for missing quarters

print earnings
```

Results like this (Numbers are random. Notice `NaN`s):

```
2011-01-01    0.215123
2011-04-01    0.161175
2011-07-01    0.476889
2011-10-01    0.280691
2012-01-01    0.384339
2012-04-01    0.358041
2012-07-01    0.985589
2012-10-01    0.515073
2013-01-01    0.675246
2013-04-01         NaN
2013-07-01    0.379003
2013-10-01         NaN
2014-01-01    0.625809
2014-04-01    0.572225
2014-07-01    0.547720
2014-10-01    0.651770
2015-01-01         NaN
2015-04-01    0.318578
2015-07-01    0.713037
2015-10-01    0.799639
Freq: QS-JAN, Name: Earnings, dtype: float64
```

Then you can do Quarter/Quarter changes of earnings as

```
QoQ_Earnings_Chg = earnings.diff()
print QoQ_Earnings_Chg
```

Missing quarters will give you `NaN` QoQ change.

```
2011-01-01         NaN
2011-04-01   -0.053948
2011-07-01    0.315714
2011-10-01   -0.196198
2012-01-01    0.103648
2012-04-01   -0.026298
2012-07-01    0.627548
2012-10-01   -0.470516
2013-01-01    0.160172
2013-04-01         NaN
2013-07-01         NaN
2013-10-01         NaN
2014-01-01         NaN
2014-04-01   -0.053584
2014-07-01   -0.024505
2014-10-01    0.104050
2015-01-01         NaN
2015-04-01         NaN
2015-07-01    0.394458
2015-10-01    0.086602
Freq: QS-JAN, Name: Earnings, dtype: float64
```

This has diffent length from original `df` due to resampling, but you can join to `df`

```
print df.join(QoQ_Earnings_Chg, rsuffix='_QoQChg')

           Symbol      Time Earning_Date  Year Quarter Last_Quarter  Earnings  \
2015-10-01   AAPL  16:30:00   10/27/2015  2015      Q4           Q3  0.799639   
2015-07-01   AAPL  16:30:00    7/21/2015  2015      Q3           Q2  0.713037   
2015-04-01   AAPL  16:30:00    4/27/2015  2015      Q2           Q1  0.318578   
2014-10-01   AAPL  16:30:00   10/20/2014  2014      Q4           Q3  0.651770   
2014-07-01   AAPL  16:30:00    7/22/2014  2014      Q3           Q2  0.547720   
2014-04-01   AAPL  16:30:00    4/23/2014  2014      Q2           Q1  0.572225   
2014-01-01   AAPL  16:30:00    1/27/2014  2014      Q1           Q4  0.625809   
2013-07-01   AAPL  16:30:00    7/23/2013  2013      Q3           Q2  0.379003   
2013-01-01   AAPL  16:30:00    1/23/2013  2013      Q1           Q4  0.675246   
2012-10-01   AAPL  16:30:00   10/25/2012  2012      Q4           Q3  0.515073   
2012-07-01   AAPL  16:30:00    7/24/2012  2012      Q3           Q2  0.985589   
2012-04-01   AAPL  16:30:00    4/24/2012  2012      Q2           Q1  0.358041   
2012-01-01   AAPL  16:30:00    1/24/2012  2012      Q1           Q4  0.384339   
2011-10-01   AAPL  16:30:00   10/18/2011  2011      Q4           Q3  0.280691   
2011-07-01   AAPL  16:30:00    7/19/2011  2011      Q3           Q2  0.476889   
2011-04-01   AAPL  16:30:00    4/20/2011  2011      Q2           Q1  0.161175   
2011-01-01   AAPL  16:30:00    1/18/2011  2011      Q1          NaN  0.215123   

            Earnings_QoQChg  
2015-10-01         0.086602  
2015-07-01         0.394458  
2015-04-01              NaN  
2014-10-01         0.104050  
2014-07-01        -0.024505  
2014-04-01        -0.053584  
2014-01-01              NaN  
2013-07-01              NaN  
2013-01-01         0.160172  
2012-10-01        -0.470516  
2012-07-01         0.627548  
2012-04-01        -0.026298  
2012-01-01         0.103648  
2011-10-01        -0.196198  
2011-07-01         0.315714  
2011-04-01        -0.053948  
2011-01-01              NaN
```

Comment: Whoa.  Thanks.  This one I will definitely learn something from trying to implement on my own.  Definitely a heavy duty solution rather than the bandaids I was dreaming up!  I will test and get back to you tomorrow.  Rly appreciate you loading my data in and building this out.

Comment: Can you explain the 'QS' string?  Thanks.  Also, at this stage of my script, I don't have any earnings data in there in terms of 'results'.  I could certainly populate with random like you do before doing the diff - but just asking if ... that changes anything in terms of your answer.

Comment: I think QS means quarter starting. Without actual earnings you can resample any numerical column. Or create one (can be constant) as placeholder if you don't have one.